# ajax photo album with text description

Tags: ajax, photo-gallery

I'm trying to create a little ajax photo album with text description... now I've created this http://www.brucisystems.com/petrilli/testajax.html

Now, what I want to do is to remove the dropdown list, insert the first photo with description when I oped the gallery, and to put a button on the bottom of the gallery, and clicking on this button then the picture and description changes, but the problem is that I have no idea of how to make it: do you have some hints?

Thanks a lot

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just move

```
<div id="txtHint"><b>la foto apparir&agrave; qua</b></div>
```

at the very top? IT will do your needs

Comment: ok, but my biggest problem is how to load the first picture in this box when I load the page, and then to create button to go to the next/previous photo

Comment: Ive created a button <?php echo "<a href=\"#\" onclic=\"showUser(".($idfirstpic+1).")\">next</a>"; ?> but when I click on this one the page doesn't refresh... do you have some hints? thanks